# MySQL Fetch week wise row count for every value of date column

Tags: mysql, sql

I've a table `delivery_trips` with a column `trip_date`. I want week wise row count for every date in column `trip_date`.

For example if it has 3 dates:

- `2022-03-17`
- `2022-03-16`
- `2022-03-15`

I want weekly row count from `2022-03-17` to `2022-03-10`.
For second resulted row, weekly row count from `2022-03-16` to `2022-03-09`. For third one, weekly row count from `2022-03-15` to `2022-03-08`. I've tried many queries but I don't get desired results. Below is one of among many queries that I tried.

```
select 
  distinct trip_date, 
  (
    select 
      count(delivery_trip_id) 
    from 
      delivery_trips T2 
    where 
      T2.trip_date between T1.trip_date - 6 
      and T1.trip_date
  ) as total_data 
from 
  delivery_trips T1
```

Comment: I think your query looks good except for maybe the subtraction of the days in your date. Try changing your query to something like this:

`select distinct trip_date, (select count(delivery_trip_id) from delivery_trips T2 where T2.trip_date between date_sub(T1.trip_date, interval 7 day) and T1.trip_date) as total_data from delivery_trips T1`

You might need to do more try/fail runs in order to make it work, but I did see one problem in the query and that is that you were treating your `date` column as if it was a `string` column when it's not

Comment: It worked! Thanks a bunch, it was of great help to me :).